# How to run second test without reload page

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, nunit

I'm trying to create Tests of my Web Page by using Selenium and i have stuck in one place. I need to run few test on same Tab on web page but without reloading it. It sound easy but i also added some kind of solution that will allow me to run same tests in many browsers. Let me explain my problem by showing some more code:

Bronswer enum:

```
public enum Browser
{
    InternetExplorer,
    FireFox,
    Chrome
}
```

This code will be used in future for switching betwen Browsers,

Main Base Class :

```
[TestFixture(Browser.InternetExplorer)]
[TestFixture(Browser.FireFox)]
[TestFixture(Browser.Chrome)]
public class TestBase
{
    protected RemoteWebDriver Driver;
    protected Browser BrowserType;
    protected List<Browser> BronswersToRun;
    internal TestBase(Browser browser) : this(browser, new List<Browser>())
    {
    }

    public TestBase(Browser browser, List<Browser> bronswersToRun)
    {
        BrowserType = browser;
        BronswersToRun = bronswersToRun;
    }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public virtual void SetUp()
    {
        if (BronswersToRun.Any() && !BronswersToRun.Contains(BrowserType))
        {
            Assert.Ignore();
        }
        switch (BrowserType)
        {
            case Browser.Chrome:
                {
                    Driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
                }
            case Browser.FireFox:
                {
                    Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
                }
            case Browser.InternetExplorer:
                {
                    var options = new InternetExplorerOptions { IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true };
                    Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                Assert.Ignore();
                break;
        }
    }
    [SetUp]
    public virtual void BeforeEachBase()
    {
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:MyWebPage/");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public virtual void AfterAllBase()
    {

    }
    ~TestBase()
    {
        Driver.Close();
    }
}
```

This Class allow me to run test in more than one internet browser if I want. I will pass list of Browsers in constructor ( right now hardcoded in furure from settings ) so if Browsers in not in list tests will be ignored for this one.

Base Class for Tab Test:

```
public class TabTestBase : TestBase
{
    protected IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> SearchElemens;
    public TabTestBase(Browser s):base(s,new List<Browser>{Browser.InternetExplorer})
    {
    }

    public override void BeforeEachBase()
    {
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:MyWebPage/Tab");
    }
}
```

This code will be used as Base Class for Testing separate Tab.

And The Tab Tests Class :

```
[TestFixture]
public class TabTest : TabTestBase
{
    public TabTest(Browser s) : base(s)
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
          //Tests
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
          //Tests
    }
}
```

Overall everything work fine. When `TabTest` Class is runned it starting my web page on this Tab and start testing it. Problem is that every single test run my `BeforeEachBase()` method form `TabTestBase` so it just unnecessary refresh this page. I want to make code that will run Tab only one and next will leave it. I can't load Web Page in constructor because in my code when Constructor of `TabTestBase` or `TabTest` is runned `Driver` object is not set yet so this solution is bad. I have 2 working solutions but they looks very unprofessional.

Frist:

Add parameters that will check that `BeforeEachBase()` was runned, and if yes just skip it like :

```
public override void BeforeEachBase()
{
    if (firstRun)
    {
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:MyWebPage/Tab");
        firstRun = false;
     }   
}
```

But this look in my opinion very unprofessional. Second working idea is even worst :

Is just add to navigate to url in first test `Test1` instead of in `BeforeEachBase` method :

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
       Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:MyWebPage/Tab");
       // TESTS
}
```

But as i said this is even worst than 1st idea.

So my question is : Is there any way to do this nice and clear ? Just to not refresh page every time ?

Just a bonus question :

Right now i can run test on 3 different browsers one by one. Is there any way to rebuild my code to do this in one time ( Parallel or Multithread ? )

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your

```
[SetUp]
public virtual void BeforeEachBase()
{
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:MyWebPage/");
}
```

This method will run before every single `[Test]`, and it will cause the behavior you are seeing, I recommend removing this method all together, and  update your `[TestFixtureSetUp]` at the very end of it add

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:MyWebPage/");
```

This will ensure that the navigation happens only once per fixture, `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` are test specific meaning they will run before and after each test.

Comment: Noo :) There is no way that i could be so stupid that I don't get this :) Nice this one work perfectly :) Much Thanks :) Any ideas about Parallel ? Maybe this is also so simple :)

Comment: Glad i could help, in terms of parallel, lets start by which version of nunit are you using?,

Comment: Right now i have version `2.6.3`

Comment: I dont think its possible with that version, but the newer version of nunit has alot of nice additions and parallelism is one of them https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallel-Test-Execution 
Please do not forget to mark this as the accepted answer if you are happy with it

Comment: So i will have to upgrade my NUnit in near future :) Thanks for help :)

Comment: No problem :) i just went thru nunit upgrade myself recently jumped from 2.6.4 to latest, was a pain at the beginning, but now its totally worth it